# Ruby Recursion doesn't work?

Tags: ruby, algorithm, recursion

I was trying to make a recursive algorithm with Ruby and I couldn't do it so I kept *popping the stack* as it were and each time I tried a simpler recursive algorithm to see where my mistake was..

But I arrived at this:

```
def fact(n)
  if n==0
    1
  else
    fact(n)*fact(n-1)  
  end
end

puts fact(5)
```

**and**

```
ruby/part2.rb:81: stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
```

Ok what is going on?

Is it not possible to make recursive algorithms in Ruby??

Comment: Seriously? Here's a hint: Option a) Over the course of the 20 years of Ruby's existence, hundreds of thousands of Ruby developers have *never* noticed that Ruby doesn't actually work. Option b) there's a bug in your code. Which one is more likely?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

your algorithm is incorrect, it should look like this

```
def fact(n)
  if n==0
    1
  else
   n*fact(n-1)  
  end
end

puts fact(5)
```

Comment: I see.. SO that's it? I can use recursion in Ruby as I would in C or Java?

Comment: More generally, each recursive invocation must decrease the size of the problem (by calling `fact(n)` you were keeping the size of it). And, of course, factorials are calculated as Doboy says.

Comment: Ok. Your algorithm is better I agree. But then why does the edited algorithm also give out the same error?

Comment: Because when it reaches fact(1), it calls fact(-1), and -1 being different from 0, it goes on and on in negative numbers...

Comment: and by the way your algorithm is NOT factorial, it's something else. fact(n) = n * fact(n-1)

Answer (score 2):

`fact(n) * fact(n - 1)` is infinite recursion. You need to reduce the problem size in each call.

```
def fact(n)
  if n <= 0
    1
  else
    n * fact(n - 1)  
  end
end
```

---

Or simply,

```
def fact(n)
  n <= 0 ? 1 : n * fact(n - 1)  
end
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to do something like fact(n-1)*fact(n-2) because otherwise, fact(n),n=5 will be called forever.

Comment: Well yeah, when you do fact(n-2) you skip the check n==0, but if you change the code to check for n<0 it will work. But still using it this way you will end up with one, because the values will drop until they reach value 1.

Comment: `fact(n) != fact(n-1)*fact(n-2)` by counter example, `(3!) != (2!)*(1!)`

Comment: I never said that I offered a solution to his problem. I only offered a solution to the recursion error. Check yourself better!